# How to study positivity of $x\sqrt{4-x^2}-4\arcsin({\frac x2})$

Tags: inequality

I have to study where the function is positive/negative. What's the method to solve the inequality $x\sqrt{4-x^2}-4\arcsin({\frac x2})>0$ ?

Comment: Hint:  Let $x = 2\sin t$ for $t \in [-\frac{\pi}2, \frac{\pi}2]$.  Does that simplify things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of $f(x) = x \sqrt{4-x^2} - \sin^{-1} (x/2)$ is negative since it equals to $f'(x) = -2x^2/ \sqrt{4-x^2}$ so the function $f$ is decreasing for $x$ positive and in the domain of $f$ so for $x$ between $0$ and $2$. Now since $f(0)=0$ then the function is negative between 0 and 2. On the other hand the function $f$ is odd, so it is positive for $x$ negative, f(0)=0 and negative for $x$ positive (of course for $x$ in the  domain of $f$ between -2 and 2.)

Answer (score 1):

Replacing $x$ with $2y$, we have to study:
$$ y\sqrt{1-y^2}-\arcsin y $$
or, by replacing $y$ with $\sin\theta$,
$$ \sin\theta\cos\theta-\theta $$
that is clearly negative for positive $\theta$ since $\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\theta)<\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2\theta = \theta.$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

- $\sqrt{x}$ positive. but only reel for $x \geq 0$.
- $4-x^2$ positive for $x \leq 2$
- $x$ positive if $x$ positive
- $\arcsin(x)$ looks like this:

[image]

...

Answer (score 0):

you can make life easier if you look at the function $f(x) = x \sqrt{1-x^2} - \sin^{-1} x.$  observe that $f(0) = 0, f(1) = -\pi/2$

take the derivative and show that it is negaive on $0 \le x \le 1$

note $4f(x/2) = x \sqrt{4-x^2} - 4 \arcsin(x/2)$